# Pagination not working on multiple querying

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a multiple query, but for some reason the pagination is not working, i dont no if the ussue is the way i construct it.

My code:

```
 $query = \DB::table('products');


   if ($request->has('type') && $type) {
        $query->where('product_type_id', $type);
    }

    if ($request->has('material') && $material) {
      $query->join("product_attribute_materials","products.id","=","product_attribute_materials.product_id")
        ->whereIn("product_attribute_materials.product_material_id", $material);
    }

    if($request->has('businessarea') && $area){
        $query->join("product_attribute_businessareas","products.id","=","product_attribute_businessareas.product_id")
        ->whereIn("product_attribute_businessareas.product_businessarea_id", $area);
    }

    $products = $query->paginate(15);
```

Comment: What is the output of `dd($query->paginate(15));` ?

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting an error? If so please give the error. Or if you're not getting the results you expect please specify what you expect and what you're actually getting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the query string to the pagination using `append()` on `$products`

Passing array with the keys that you want to pass the query string, will return its value on the next request.

To confirm this, chick the href value from your browser before clicking on page number 2.

`$products = $query->paginate(15)->appends(['type', 'material', 'businessarea']);`